# User scope vs Application scope in app.config

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

What is the difference between the User scope and Application scope in app.config?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User-scope settings are used to store values specific to each individual user, whereas application-scope settings are used for all users.

Take a look at this [article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34273/1954).

Answer (score 8):

User Scoped Settings will only affect the current user and are relatively safe to set.  They are stored in a user specific location so there is no real issue with writing to them.

Application Scoped Settings on the other hand are read-only and cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

**Application-scoped** vs. **User-scoped Settings**:

**Application-scoped settings**:

- Apply to all users of the application.
- Typically stored in the App.config or Web.config file.
- Typically used for settings that affect the overall application behavior, such as server URLs, connection strings, feature flags, application paths and default values.
- Cannot be modified by users at runtime.
- Must be explicitly saved using My.Settings.Save() if changes are made programmatically.

**User-scoped settings**:

- Apply to individual users of the application.
- Stored in a user.config file, located in each user's application data
  folder.
- Typically used for settings that personalize the user experience, such as preferences (e.g. Preferred language), layout choices, window size, last-used document paths and toolbar configuration.
- Can be modified by users at runtime.
- Changes are automatically saved to the user.config file.