# Relationship between the "app.config" and "user.config" files?

Tags: c#, winforms

What's the relationship between the `app.config` stored in the root of the project and the `user.config` file stored in `C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\...`?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622782/user-scope-vs-application-scope-in-app-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, **app.config** stores information that is application-wide (applied to all users) and read-only. While **user.config** stores information that is user-specific and typically can be written to as they are stored in a specific location per user.

In Visual Studio, you can edit either User Scope or Application Scope settings like this:

[image]

When creating the particular property setting just choose Scope to indicate how you wish the information to persist. The **user.config** file will only be created when you have made changes to the default value of a User-Scope setting and it will only contain those settings whose values have changed from the defaults stored in the **app.config**.

Comment: to create user.config you edit Project>Properties>Settings, what do you suppose to edit to manage app.config and where does it located?

Comment: I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: You can add app.config per project if it is not already present. Its an xml file that contain project specific information. You can open it in VS or any other text editor to edit it.

Comment: Correct, you can also edit the app.config file directly as @SBirthare has suggested - Just make sure that you are formatting the markup correctly. It's also noteworthy that the user.config file will only be created when you have made changes to the default of a User-scope setting and it will only contain those settings whose values have changed.